# May I ask you how to find the coordinates of the segmented pixels?

Tags: python, opencv, coordinates

I already have two image segmentation codes using the k-means clustering method and watershed segmentation.
By the way, Can I extract the xy coordinates where the straight line with mouse event overlaps with the area with the segmented specific color?
I keep trying, and I only see the coordinates of the straight line drawn with the mouse.
please help me

Is there any good way to fine the distance between segment areas within a specific area of a segmented image?

This is the part of code that I keep trying to find the coordinates:

```
lines = []
line_start = (-1, -1)

#segmented_image is the image segmented using k-means clustering
gray_region = zeros_like(segmented_image)
gray_region[np.all(segmented_image) == [105, 104, 105], axis = -1))] = [105, 104, 105]

for coord_x in range(line_start[0], x+1):
    for coord_y in range(line_start[1], y+1):
        if np.array_equal(segmented_image[coord_y, coord_x], [0, 255, 0]) and \   
        np.array_equal(gray_region[coord_y, coord_x], [105, 104, 105]):
        print(f'line coordinate ({coord_x}, {coord_y}) is in the segmented region.")
```